# grab a string from a list and plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

As part of a more complicated issue, I am trying to grab a string from a list that matches a variable I want to plot.

```
# http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(cond = factor( rep(c("A","B"), each=200) ), 
                 rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))
library(ggplot2)
myList <- list(something=c("rating", "foo1"),
               else=c("foo2", "foo3"))
myList[[1]][1] # [1] "rating"

# does not work
  ggplot(df, aes(x=myList[[1]][1])) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
# works
  ggplot(df, aes(x=rating)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
```

I want to get `rating` from my list rather than type it directly. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: try `aes_string` in the first ggplot call instead of `aes`

Comment: I just closed it so it doesn't persist as an unanswered question and used a pointer to another question with a somewhat richer application of hte aes_string capacities as the "duplicate".

Comment: I'd be happy to add @NicE's comment as an answer. I did not come across the duplicate in my search because I did not know about `aes_string`.